# PHP equivalent to pythons slots

Tags: php, html, css, web

I'm not really sure how to sum this up as a google question but maybe explaining it in detail will get me better help.

I'm trying to find the equivalent to setting up slots in python in PHP

Python:

```
class Node:
    slots = ('name','desc','blah')
    def __init__(self, name, desc, blah):
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.blah = blah
```

Running through an array and I hate trying to remember what position somethings at and doing array[3] or what ever so doing array.blah would be much easier. Is this possible in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one issue with the approach above and thats it that in an array you can add new values on the fly. I am not sure how slots work exactly since im not familiar with python but looking at the example the keys name, desk and blah should be constant and they are pre-defined. The best approach in that case would be to use class members in my opinion such as

```
      Class Node{
    private $name;
    private $desc;
    private $blah;

    public function __construct($name, $desc, $blah){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->desc = $desk;
    $this->blah = $blah;
    }
}
```

You could of course make the variables public but its not the best approach, instead you should probably implement getters and setters for each variable.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it was close to python but I just had no clue what to search for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use an associative array:

```
$slots = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'desc' => $desc,
    'blah' => $blah
);
```

Then you can do `echo $slots['name'];`

Cheers

Comment: you forgot quotes around the values.